# ExtJS: split window into two collapsible parts

Tags: javascript, layout, split, extjs3

How can I split my page into two collapsible parts (top & bottom) with ExtJS?
Viewport with border layout will not work without center region, that cannot be collapsed.
Accordion layout is not the thing I need.

Is it possible to do such a thing with Ext 3.3.1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use vBox layout on Containers (check the ExtJs Layout Example for inspiration http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) that each hold a custom Component that can collapse the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using border layout only but a dummy center panel with hidden true...

Answer (score 0):

You use anchor layout whereby the components that you are using in the two sections can be collapse separately and you need to implement listeners to adjust the size of the sections when they are collapsed.